# Roman italic labels in r

Tags: r, plot, lattice

I have a very simple script:

```
sens = read.table("Myfile.txt")
library(lattice)
contourplot(sens$V1 ~ sens$V2+sens$V3,data=d3,xlab="U",ylab=expression(kappa))
```

I have been trying to get my labels in roman italic font. I thought

```
font.lab=3, family="serif"
```

should give me exactly this but whatever I try (font=3,font="italic"...) just doesn't change the font at all.

Can anybody spot what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the `italic` function and unicode symbols.

```
require(lattice)
require(grid)
x <- seq(pi/4, 5 * pi, length.out = 100)
y <- seq(pi/4, 5 * pi, length.out = 100)
r <- as.vector(sqrt(outer(x^2, y^2, "+")))
grid <- expand.grid(x=x, y=y)
grid$z <- cos(r^2) * exp(-r/(pi^3))

contourplot(z~x*y, grid, cuts = 1,
  colorkey = FALSE, region = TRUE,
  xlab=expression(italic(U)),
  ylab=expression(italic('\u03ba')))
grid.gedit("text", gp=gpar(fontfamily="serif"))
grid.gedit("xlab", gp=gpar(fontfamily="serif"))
grid.gedit("ylab", gp=gpar(fontfamily="serif"))
```

Comment: Thank you. This is only getting my text in italic but not in roman italic.

Comment: I also added a method using the grid package.

Answer (score 2):

Setting up a theme will allow you to change these globally.

```
font.settings <- list(font = 3, fontfamily = "serif")

my.theme <- list(par.xlab.text = font.settings,
                 par.ylab.text = font.settings,
                 axis.text = list(fontfamily = "serif"))
```

Then add `par.settings = my.theme` to the contourplot statement

```
contourplot(sens$V1 ~ sens$V2+sens$V3,data=d3,xlab="U",ylab=expression(kappa), 
            par.settings = my.theme)
```

Comment: Thanks Kevin. This is partly solving my problem because now I am not only getting the axes titles in roman italic, but also the labels (or scale) on my graph in roman italic, which I do not want.

Answer (score 1):

Although Triad Sou's answer worked on the R Graphics window, the labels were still in a non-serif font when I tried to print the plot in an eps format with the command:

```
dev.print(device=postscript,file="Myfile.eps")
```

So for my eps file I had to do:

```
contourplot(sens$Tot ~ sens$U+sens$kappa,data=d3,
        xlab=expression(italic(U)),ylab=expression(italic(kappa)))
dev.print(device=postscript,file="Myfile.eps",family="serif")
```

Comment: Postscript doesn't know family = "serif". Try PDF. Either solution should work with PDF.